# Embed Power Virtual Agents bot in Sharepoint site page?

Tags: embedded, chatbot

I am able to get a PVA bot on a Sharepoint page. I created a new section and embedded the usual code to embed on a custom site.

```
<iframe src="https://powerva.microsoft.com/webchat/bots/XXX" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
```

That works, but the problem is that it's "stuck" in that section. I want it to fix it to the bottom right. I tried adding a little to the style tag so that the entire code was like this:

```
<iframe src="https://powerva.microsoft.com/webchat/bots/XXX" frameborder="0" style="width: 300px; height: 400px; position: fixed; bottom: 0px; right: 0"></iframe>
```

It's hard to explain what that did, but in basically broke the page for some reason. I wasn't able to scroll down the page or click on anything. I had to revert to a previous version of the page.

Is it possible to embed a Power Virtual Agents bot on a Sharepoint page with expected results?

Comment: I am trying the same thing, is it possible to embed a Power Virtual Agents bot on a Sharepoint page